# Disappearing WPF controls after 'Arrange' with Infinity size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm facing an odd bug for around a month onwards.

I have a form that looks like this :

[image]

When I click on Save picture :

```
        var g = new Grid();
        var mv = new MyControl();
        g.Children.Add(mv);
        g.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        g.Arrange(new Rect(g.DesiredSize)); 

        var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)g.ActualWidth, (int)g.ActualHeight,
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(g);
```

Calling Measure() and Arrange() sets the size of the grid with proper size ( retrieved from `MyControl` )
The form control and the user control being rendered on the `RenderTargetBitmap` share no common data.

The visuals which become hidden are there and the viewmodel data is populated properly.

After executing this code and showing the dialog again it looks like this :

[image]

Both of the checkboxes have disappeared.Why?!

This problem doesn't appear if I set the size of the grid ( `var g` in the code )

```
        var g = new Grid()
        {
            Width = 1024,
            Height = 768
        };
```

Comment: @flag for close..What isn't clear in my question?

Comment: You yourself said the answer. While creating a new grid, you must specify the `Width` and `Height` else add the new control to existing grid.

Comment: @ViVi But I do call Measure() and Arrange..

Comment: There is definitely something important that you haven't shown us. The "cancel" button can't appear out of nowhere either. There has to be a reason why it appeared only the 2nd time.

Comment: I too agree with Jai. I am also wondering how that Cancel button popped up from nowhere. There is no related code found either.

Comment: @ViVi the cancel button is completely unrelated, the only problem are the checkboxes.Tried to omit the rest of the stuff ( such as the cancel button ), sorry for confusing you with it:)

Answer (score 0):

The default `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` for `Grid` is `1*`. This means that the contents are given however much space the `Grid` has. In this case, the `Grid` will ask its parent to give it the maximum amount of space available for itself.

In your case, because your `Grid` has no visual parent, it has no idea how big it should render itself. You need to give it an explicit width/height. If you want to convert the contents of `MyControl` into Bitmap, why not just do it without the `Grid`?

If you insist on using Grid, and the size is dynamic, then you should manually specify the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions`. Change both of them to `auto`, which would force the Grid to size itself to the contents' sizes.

Comment: The control gives the correct size to the grid when we call MEasure() and Arrange(). I can confirm that the size of the grid at runtime is not Nan, and the image produced is correct.

Comment: @Chris Then you need to provide more codes. So far we cannot see what's the link between the RenderTargetBitmap and your UserControl. Also, you need to be more specific what "opening again" means.

Comment: There's no link between the form and the user control being rendered. Infact only changing those 2 properties : Width and Height is the difference between the two results I've depicted with images..

Answer (score 0):

As said on [MSDN info about Measure (Remarks section)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Computation of layout positioning in Windows Presentation Foundation
>   (WPF) is comprised of a Measure call and an Arrange call. During the
>   Measure call, an element determines its size requirements by using an
>   availableSize input. During the Arrange call, the element size is
>   finalized.
>
> availableSize can be any number from zero to infinite. Elements
>   participating in layout should return the minimum Size they require
>   for a given availableSize.
>
> When a layout is first instantiated, it always receives a Measure call
>   before Arrange. However, after the first layout pass, it may receive
>   an Arrange call without a Measure; this can happen when a property
>   that affects only Arrange is changed (such as alignment), or when the
>   parent receives an Arrange without a Measure. A Measure call will
>   automatically invalidate an Arrange call.
>
> Layout updates happen `asynchronously`, such that the main thread is
>   not waiting for every possible layout change. Querying an element via
>   code-behind checking of property values may not immediately reflect
>   changes to properties that interact with the sizing or layout
>   characteristics (the Width property, for example).
>
> Layout updates can be forced by using the `UpdateLayout` method.
>   However, calling this method is usually unnecessary and can cause poor
>   performance.

Hence call `g.UpdateLayout` in your save picture button click.

```
var g = new Grid();
var mv = new MyControl();
g.Children.Add(mv);
g.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
g.Arrange(new Rect(g.DesiredSize));
g.UpdateLayout();

var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)g.ActualWidth, (int)g.ActualHeight,
    96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rtb.Render(g);
```

Comment: This looks interesting, altho it doesn't solve my problem ( checkboxes still missing ).

Comment: Require more code for analyzing your problem. Or else compare the first scenario xaml code with the picture button click code. Some property you might have missed to set I suppose.